# get Client IP Symfony3

Tags: symfony

How to get client ip address in form builder symfony?

I have class CompanyType.php (AppBundle/Form/CompanyType.php)

```
$builder->add('ip', TextType::class, array(
    'label'=> 'IP Address',
    'data' => '127.0.0.1'
));
```

I want to get the current client ip address that someone is using and put it on data parameters. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this should work:

```
$ip = $this->request->getClientIp();
if($ip == 'unknown'){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

The `getClientIp()` function looks for the `X-Forwarded-For` header, which may not be set. If not then you can just get the IP address out of the `$_SERVER` variable like in any other PHP page.

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getClientIp

Comment: Hi I receive an error: Undefined property: SwipeBundle\Form\CompanyType::$request

Comment: Does it work if you use: `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?

Comment: No its not working, fyi please, there is no request in my FormType.

Comment: Are you using some kind of proxy (Nginx, Varnish, Lighthttpd )?

Comment: @jlacsonph Well, by all means, pass the `$request` from your controller to your form type.

Comment: @JovanPerovic sorry Im new in sf3 how do i do that?

Comment: @jlacsonph Please update the question with your from type code so we could give an example ;)

Answer (score 4):

The correct method in a controller is:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

....

public function myMethodAction(Request $request)
{
    $ip = $request->getClientIp();
    .....

}
```